# Count exact row matches in a dataframe

Tags: r

Let's say I have a dataframe `df` and an example row `sample <- df[1,]`.

How can I count occurrences of `sample` in `df`?

From what I found so far, it should be something like `sum(df==sample)`, but I get an error

`‘==’ only defined for equally-sized data frames`.

For example:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(20), nrow=10))
df <- rbind(df, df[1,])
sample <- df[1,]

unlist(sample)[col(df)]==df

      X1    X2
1   TRUE  TRUE
2  FALSE FALSE
3  FALSE FALSE
4  FALSE FALSE
5  FALSE FALSE
6  FALSE FALSE
7  FALSE FALSE
8  FALSE FALSE
9  FALSE FALSE
10 FALSE FALSE
11  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: The `==` works only for equal-sized datasets.  You may need to show a small reproducible example.  Perhaps `unlist(sample)[col(df)]==df` assuming the dimensions are correct

Comment: Thank you! That's almost what I need. (Added an example)

Comment: You need `colSums(unlist(sample)[col(df)]==df)`

Comment: That's it - many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use merge then count rows:

```
# reproducible example data
set.seed(1)
df1 <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(20), nrow = 10))
# add duplicate row
df1 <- rbind(df1, df1[1,])
df1_sample <- df1[1,]

# merge and get number of rows
nrow(merge(df1_sample, df1))
# [1] 2
```

Comment: @user5226582 df and sample are R function, try to avoid using them as variable names. I will update my post with different names.

Comment: I just tried to "anonymize" my data, actual names are different; but I still didn't know that, so thank you.